# Get chart data point cell reference

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I am trying to get some underlying data from a chart.

I have the below that loops through the chart and can access the data points, for example values of labels etc

```
Sub GetChartPoints()

  Dim mySrs As Series
  Dim iPts As Long
  Dim bLabeled As Boolean

  If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Select a chart and try again.", vbExclamation
  Else
    For Each mySrs In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
      bLabeled = False
      With mySrs
        For iPts = .Points.Count To 1 Step -1
            Debug.Print "w"
            Debug.Print mySrs.Points(iPts).HasDataLabel
            If mySrs.Points(iPts).HasDataLabel Then
                Debug.Print mySrs.Points(iPts).DataLabel.Text
                mySrs.Points(iPts).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                Debug.Print mySrs.Values(iPts)
                Debug.Print mySrs.XValues(iPts)
            End If
        Next
      End With
    Next
  End If

End Sub
```

What I would like to do is get other values from the data that this is based on, for example: if the data point references cell C4 I want to return that (my step would then be to get the value form say E4 and so something with that).

Is it possible to get the cell that a data point points to

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it, just need to add a few `Objects` and get a little *crafty*.

See your code, and addition section below (I marked it in the code).

You can save a few objects and parameters, I just wanted to show the work done step-by-step.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetChartPoints()

Dim mySrs As Series
Dim iPts As Long
Dim bLabeled As Boolean

If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Select a chart and try again.", vbExclamation
Else
    For Each mySrs In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
        bLabeled = False
        With mySrs
            For iPts = .Points.Count To 1 Step -1
                Debug.Print "w"
                Debug.Print mySrs.Points(iPts).HasDataLabel

                If mySrs.Points(iPts).HasDataLabel Then
                    Debug.Print mySrs.Points(iPts).DataLabel.Text
                    mySrs.Points(iPts).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                    Debug.Print mySrs.Values(iPts)
                    Debug.Print mySrs.XValues(iPts)

                    ' ========= Addition start here =========
                    Dim RangeAddress As String, PointAddress As String
                    Dim SerValuesRng As Range, PointRng As Range

                    ' get the Range Address of the current series (Values)
                    RangeAddress = Split(mySrs.Formula, ",")(2)

                    ' set a Range object according to the result of the Address string
                    Set SerValuesRng = Range(RangeAddress)

                    ' Get the Cell location of current point in the Sereis range
                    Set PointRng = SerValuesRng.Cells(iPts)

                    ' Address of the PointRng
                    PointAddress = PointRng.Address(0, 0, xlA1, xlExternal)

                    ' for debug only
                    Debug.Print PointAddress
                    ' ========= Addition ends here =========

                End If
            Next
        End With
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Just what I needed.  I just use something like this to get data relative to where the point is - Range(PointAddress).Offset(0, -1).Value - thanks